# Cannot find DDMS in android studio 2.2.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2.3

I recently updated Android Studio to version 2.2.3(Windows), Android Device Monitor is running but cannot locate DDMS button to view Hierarchy Viewer.

Update : I found that in Windows 'Run As Administrator' can open Android Device Monitor but it displayed this error dialog.[image]

Comment: please tell the OS you are using?

Comment: i'm not sure but u can try this: download jdk(version which suits you) & then install it. Then copy the javaw.exe from your C:\program files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin folder to the given path on the android eg:C:\Users\ASUS X550L\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\tools\lib\monitor-x86_64 And then run the javaw.exe as administrator.

Comment: I did try this step but again same error.

Comment: try by killing or ending "monitor.exe" running process using Taskmanager in Windows. Then click ADM (Android Device Monitor)

Comment: Ya it's running now.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac navigate to:

`Tools -> Android -> Android Device Monitor`

[image]

**EDIT**

In reply to OP's this comment:

*Android device monitor is running but cannot find DDMS.*

I can see the option at my side:

[image]

Comment: Android device monitor is running but cannot find DDMS.

Answer (score 0):

Same on linux:

```
Tools -> Android -> Android Device Monitor
```

[image]

Comment: Android device monitor is running but cannot find DDMS.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same issue and it turns out that a notification message was in the background and never brought it forward. opening the task manager you should see monitor process, right clicking it and selecting "switch to" brought the notification forward and allowed me to continue.